# Laravel Vue Inertia Show Component with Data in Dashboard Undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, undefined, inertiajs

I'm practicing a bit with Laravel, Vue and Inertia. I have the following problem now. I have created a Dashboard.vue page and various components that are displayed as a section on this dashboard. Generally I can see the section with the included components. Like:

```
<section class="overflow-x-auto w-full">
 <Search />
</section>
```

However, I have a component that loads data from the MySQL database. These are not shown values from Database in the dashboard. Only

```
"<p v-else> No hins available.</p"
```

Hin.vue:

```
  <template>
  <div>
    <ul v-if="hins && hins.length > 0">
      <li v-for="hin in hins" :key="hin.id">
        {{ hin.id }} - {{ hin.hin }} - {{ hin.description }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p v-else>No hins available.</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, defineProps } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  hins: Array,
});
</script>
```

Dashboard like this:

```
<script setup>
import { Head, Link } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import Test1 from "./Test1.vue";
import Test2 from "./Test2.vue";
import Hin from "./Hin.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";

</script>

<script>
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue";

export default {
    layout: AuthenticatedLayout,
};
</script>

<template>
    <Head title="Dashboard" />
        <section>
          <Test1 />
         </section>

         <section>
           <Test2 />
          </section>

          <section>
            <Hin />
           </section>
           
           <section>

            </section>
  </template>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Hin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;

class HinController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $hins = Hin::get();

        return Inertia::render('Hin', [
            'hins' => $hins,
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
dd($hins); = Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1502 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/HinController.php:14 #items: array:130 [▶] #escapeWhenCastingToString: false }
```

Vue Dev-Tool: props hins:undefined

Console log: undefined

web.php:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->get('/hin', [HinController::class, 'index']);
```

Maybe I've made a thinking error here or missed something in the docs - can someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: What errors, exactly, are you seeing? Is anything showing up from the Hin.vue view? Any errors in the console? What happens if you call `dd($hins);` right after `$hins = Hin::get();` in your controller?

Comment: Here http://127.0.0.1:8000/hin I can see the table from my database. Here http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard <section><Hin /></section> "No hins available." Console error "undefined" same as in Vue Dev-Tool: props hins:undefined. Hope this helps to find my problem? Thank you

Comment: Again, what happens when you "dump and die" in the controller?

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1502 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/HinController.php:14
  #items: array:130 [▶]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}

Comment: Consider giving your question an [edit], showing images and more code, as needed. Showing the route might help as well.

Comment: okay I will do, thank you

Comment: So, maybe I'm misunderstanding things, but it looks to me like you're showing Hin.vue inside of Dashboard.vue, not from `\hin` url or from Laravel, and so Hin is not receiving any data from Laravel, and is not receiving props from Dashboard, and so it would make sense that the it would not see props.

Comment: Does the payload, `'hins' => $hins,` need to be delivered to the Dashboard vue, and then passed into `<Hins  hins=hinsProps />` via Vue props?

Comment: .............hello?

Answer (score 1):

You state,

> Here 127.0.0.1:8000/hin I can see the table from my database. Here 127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard  "No hins available." Console error "undefined" same as in Vue Dev-Tool: props hins:undefined. Hope this helps to find my problem?

And this makes sense.

- When your url has `/hin`, e.g., `127.0.0.1:8000/hin` then you obtain the Hins.vue page via the Laravel router which calls the HinController.php `index()` method, and the data that is desired is neatly packaged in the controller is sent to the view:

```
return Inertia::render('Hin', [
    'hins' => $hins,
]);
```

- However, when you try to display Hins.vue within another Vue page, you are not getting the hins page directly from the Laravel router, and so the HinController is never accessed and its `index()` method never called, and so no data is sent into Hins.vue, no props, no nothing.

One way to solve this is to obtain `$hins = Hin::get();` in your *dashboard* controller, pass it into Dashboard.vue when rendering it (so that it is a prop of Dashboard) and then pass that prop into Hins.vue as a prop.

e.g.,

```
<script setup>
import { Head, Link } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import Test1 from "./Test1.vue";
import Test2 from "./Test2.vue";
import Hin from "./Hin.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  hins: Array,
});

</script>

<script>
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue";

export default {
    layout: AuthenticatedLayout,
};
</script>

<template>
    <Head title="Dashboard" />
        <section>
          <Test1 />
         </section>

         <section>
           <Test2 />
          </section>

          <section>
            <Hin :hins="hins"/>
           </section>
           
           <section>

            </section>
  </template>
```

Other options for obtaining the data where needed include

- Vue's [Provide / Inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html).
- If you need to use a bit of data throughout the entire application, then Inertia provides the HandleInertiaRequests middleware class for this. For details on this, check out [Inertia's Shared Data](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data) link.

Answer (score -1):

So I find a solution:

Web.php

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
$hins = DB::table('hins')->get();
return Inertia::render('Dashboard',[
    'hins' => $hins
]);
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');
```

Dashboard.vue:

```
import Hin from "@/Components/Hin.vue";

const props = defineProps({hins: Array,});

<Hin :hins="hins"/>
```

Thanks to everyone

Comment: This is what I already told you to do days ago. -1 for ignoring it and wasting my time.